# Swift iOS CoreData to Flash Drive (Export and Transfer)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've written an app (to be run on an iPad) that saves entities via CoreData. However, it will be used in an environment in which wireless connections may be inhibited and file transfer may need to be done physically.

Is there any way to export the app's coredata model and saved data entities to a lightning flash drive and then import the data contents onto another iPad running the same app?

Thanks!

Comment: how large is the database?

Comment: Database size will typically be between 0.5 to 50MB or so

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky but possible.

1. Use a SQLite file for your database. [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) provides a simple interface for SQLite.
2. Get a lightning flash drive with an app that allows receiving and sending arbitrary files from and to other apps.
3. Send your your SQLite file on iPad A via `UIDocumentInteractionController` to the lighting flash drive app and store it on the drive.
4. Plug the drive into iPad B and send the file from the flash drive app to your own app.
5. Load the database from the SQLite file.

It is not possible (without custom hardware and licenses) to access a lightning flash drive directly, so you need an existing drive with own app to transport the data.

But why can't you use wireless connections anyway? Even without a cellular network or a WiFi access point you can still communicate via Bluetooth or ad hoc WiFi between the iPads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean when you say "existing drive with own app to transport data"? Do I have to write external program to be placed onto the flash disk, or have a separate file transfer app on iOS to make this happen?

You pose a good question with respect to Bluetooth. I'll open another question that involves using Airdrop as a potential sharing method.

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise answer. With "existing drive with own app" I mean a device like the SanDisk iXpand (https://www.sandisk.de/home/mobile-device-storage/ixpand) and its app iXpand Drive. To my knowledge it is not possible to build your own flash drive for iOS.